# Fast 'group by/count' std::vector<std::u16string> into a std::map<u16string, int>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a function that reads ~10000 words into a vector, I then want to group all the words into a map to 'count' how many times a certain word appears.

While the code 'works' it can sometimes take 2 seconds to re-build the map.

**NB**: Unfortunately, I cannot change the 'read' function, I have to work with the vector of `std::u16string`.

```
std::vector<std::u16string> vValues;
vValues.push_back( ... )
...

std::map<std::u16string, int> mValues;
for( auto it = vValues.begin(); it != vValues.end(); ++it )
{
  if( mValues.find( *it ) == mValues.end() )
  {
    mValues[*it] = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ++mValues[*it];
  }
}
```

How could I speed up the 'group by' while keeping track of the number of times the word appears in the vector?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `++mValues[*it];`. If it's not there, the default constructor of your `second` will be used. Wouldn't it be at 0 by default?

Comment: What about using [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)?

Comment: You can also use range-based loop, not sure if it's faster

Comment: `it can sometimes take 2 seconds to re-build the map` -- Are you running a "debug", unoptimized build, or an optimized, "release" build?  if it is not an optimized build, the timings you're seeing are not meaningful.  Please post your compiler command line to see if you are using optimizations.

Comment: Try the suggestion by @WhiZTiM to use `std::unordered_map` first.  You don’t need to compare the strings or do an in-order traversal, only count them.  Under the hood, `std::map` is usually some kind of self-balancing binary tree and `std::unordered_map` is a hash table, which should be faster.

Comment: Seriously, 10,000 words is not a lot that it would really take 2 seconds.  This looks like an issue of running a "debug" build instead of an optimized one.

Comment: I am not running in debug, but in release mode, (VS2015 default release settings for a default c++ project).

Comment: One optimization for STL containers in general is to `reserve()` their memory ahead of time: in this case, you know that the maximum number of entries is the size of your input `vector`.  Try to find some heuristic to pass to `unordered_map::rehash()`.  If you’re copying the strings, try to use weak pointers instead, since you know the vector will outlive the map and can retain ownership.

Comment: @SimonGoodman Your loop is doing two `find`'s, one explicit (you calling `find`) and one implicit by calling `map::operator [ ]`.  There is no need to call `std::find` yourself if all you want to do is use the `int` portion of the map as a counter.  Just use `[ ]` and increment the int value.

Comment: Thanks @Davislor, I will try that as soon as I have tested the other 2 functions below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) on a new key, the value of the key will be value initialized (to 0 for PODs like `int`). So, your loop can be simplified to:

```
for (auto it = vValues.begin(); it != vValues.end(); ++it)
    ++mValues[*it];
```

If there is no key `*it`, then the default value will be `0`, but then it is incremented immediately, and it becomes `1`.

If the key already exists, then it is simply incremented.

Furthermore, it doesn't look like you need the map to be ordered, so you can use a `std::unordered_map` instead, as insertion is average constant time, instead of logarithmic, which would speed it up even further.

Comment: I will try that change to see what difference it makes, I will post back some times.

Comment: After a few tests, this approach was ~30% faster in general.
I used `reserve` as well as `unordered_map`

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<std::u16string> vValues;
vValues.push_back( ... )
...

std::sort( vValues.begin(), vValues.end() );
struct counted {
  std::u16string value;
  std::size_t count;
};
std::vector<counted> result;
auto it = vValues.begin();
while (it != vValues.end()) {
  auto r = std::equal_range( it, vValues.end(), *it );
  result.push_back({ *it, r.second-r.first });
  it = r.second;
}
```

After this is done, `result` will contain `{value, count}` for each value and will be sorted.

As all work was done in contiguous containers, it should be faster than your implementation.

If you aren't allowed to mutate `vValues`, one thing you could do is create a vector of `gsl::span<char16_t>` from it then sort that, then create the `result` vector similarly.  (If you don't have `gsl::span`, write one, they aren't hard to write)

Failing that, even copying `result` once may be faster than your original solution.

Using a `gsl::span<char16_t const>` in `counted` would save some allocations as well (reuse the storage within the `vValues`, at the cost of tying their lifetimes together.

One serious concern is that if your strings are extremely long, determining that two strings are equal is expensive.  And if they have common prefixes, determining they are different can be expensive.  We do log(n) comparisons *per distinct element* in the `equal_range` code, and n log(n) in the sort; sometimes sorting (hash of string, string) pairs can be faster than sorting (string)s alone, as it makes unlike strings easy to detect.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1037519ce16ca07) with 4 different versions.  Simply change the `test1` to `test2` or `test3` or `test4`.

`test3` is fastest in every test I did:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> test3(std::vector<std::string> vValues)
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mValues;
  for( auto it = vValues.begin(); it != vValues.end(); ++it )
  {
    ++mValues[std::move(*it)];
  }
  return mValues;
}
```

than all the other versions.

Comment: I can mutate vValue, let me write a quick function to compare the old and new with 50000 word, (a doc I have handy).

Comment: If this uses a conventional sorting algorithm, this should run in O(n log n) time.  Using `std::unordered_map` is effectively a radix sort that should take linear time, and should therefore be faster for large enough inputs.

Comment: @Davislor unordered map is, sadly, a node based container.  On 4 billion entries, lg(n) only hits 32; it doesn't take many cache misses to cost you a factor of 32.  And if you have that much data, you should be using a robust database usually.

Comment: After a few tests, this approach was ~50% **slower** in general.
I used `reserve` as well as `unordered_map`. But I am re-looking at my code as it does not really make sense.

Comment: @SimonGoodman Strange; my tests show this to be 2x as fast with modest changes to your code.  How likely are collisions?  How long are strings?

Comment: @Yakk The string is ~4000000 characters, about 270000 words and 2000 unique words. But I get about the same result, (% difference), with a string 90% smaller.

Comment: Looking at the examples you posted now, but I wonder if the fact that I am using `std::u16string` would make any difference. Also, the sample text I am using is random complete webpages, (of blogs)

Comment: @SimonGoodman Aha!  You using g++?  What standard lib?  My tests do both clang and g++; the clang ones are far faster in the vector case, the g++ ones are *slower* somehow!

Answer (score 0):

And here’s an alternative.  You might consider storing a non-owning shared pointer, but if you can’t control the format of your inputs, Yakk’s suggestion of `gsl::span` might work.  This is from [the Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL).

```
std::unordered_map<std::u16string, unsigned> hash_corpus;
// constexpr float heuristic_parameter = ?;
// hash_corpus.max_load_factor(heuristic_parameter);
/* The maximum possible number of entries in the hash table is the size of
 * the input vector.
 */
hash_corpus.reserve(corpus.size());

// Paul McKenzie suggested this trick in the comments:
for ( const std::u16string& s : corpus)
    ++hash_corpus[s]; // If the key is not in the table, [] inserts with value 0.
```

Comment: Sorry, is that not the same solution as @Rakete1111?

Comment: It came out pretty close after I edited to use Paul McKenzie’s idea. I think we both used the best ideas from the comments, but I might be confused about who wrote what when.